# Tensorflow: Error when calling optimizer to minimize loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get tensorflow to minimize a loss function with respect to a variable, however, I keep getting an error and I am unsure of the cause. I have created a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def loss_func(x, target):
    return tf.pow(x - target, 2) 

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=1., name='x', dtype=tf.float32)
target = tf.constant(value=10., dtype=tf.float32)
adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
loss = lambda: loss_func(x, target)
adam_op = adam.minimize(loss, var_list=tf.trainable_variables)
```

When running this piece of code I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    adam_op = adam.minimize(loss, var_list=tf.trainable_variables)
  File "C:...\optimizer.py", line 403, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "C:...\optimizer.py", line 461, in compute_gradients
    tape.watch(var_list)
  File "C:...\backprop.py", line 808, in watch
    tape.watch(self._tape, t)
  File "C:...\tape.py", line 59, in watch
    pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_TapeWatch(tape._tape, tensor)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
SystemError: <built-in function TFE_Py_TapeWatch> returned a result with an error set
```

Does anyone know what it is I am doing wrong? Thank you. I am using tensorflow version 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are doing. It appears you are trying to optimize x towards 10. If this is the case you can just assign it to 10. Alternatively, if you will have more than one target, you can take an some sort average of those targets and assign x to that. I believe the problem in the code is that there x the input is also a trainable variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My example is rather contrived I admit, I could just set x to 10 but I was just trying to create the simplest optimization problem I could think of. In your answer you say you believe the problem is that the input x is also the trainable variable, I am unsure as to why that is a problem. Surely in any optimization problem the parameters of the model have to be input into the objective function, otherwise the objective function wouldn't change as the parameters changed and you couldn't perform any optimization at all?

Comment: I agree looking at the code it seems as though it should work but i'm not sure. I will have a further look later. I should have been more clear of what I meant as an input. Machine learning models generally `y = w * x` where w is a trainable variable and x is a user provided parameter and y is the result of your model (in this case the product of the two). When I said input I meant a user provided parameter. This is the only way I have used tensorflow before but there must be a way to accomplish your task too. You have sparked by curiosity and I will definitely have a further look into this.